# Testing a reader's EPUB 3.0 support

Tags: ebook-readers, epub

Users have asked a few good questions about `EPUB` 3.0 support, like [Which ereaders support the EPUB3 format?](https://ebooks.stackexchange.com/questions/114/which-ereaders-support-the-epub3-format), [Can `EPUB` 3.0 be viewed on `EPUB` 2 devices?](https://ebooks.stackexchange.com/questions/205/can-epub-3-0-be-viewed-on-epub-2-devices), and a question about [Epub reader limitations](https://ebooks.stackexchange.com/questions/413/epub-reader-limitations).  I was wondering: is there a way to test what `EPUB` 3.0 features a given reader, app, or platform supports?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is; [EPUBtest](http://epubtest.org/) provides a [detailed grid of supported features by reader, app, and platform](http://epubtest.org/results/), as well as an extensive [test suite](http://epubtest.org/testsuite/) for conducting your own tests.

For example, as of January 31, 2014, [Kindle for PC 1.10.6 on Windows 7 has very limited support](http://epubtest.org/rs/26/):

[image]

Note: I have no affiliation with EPUBtest; I just thought it was a handy tool.